Formation of bubbles on the water surface
So I noticed it a few days back that when a streamlined flow of water from a tap falls on a water surface you don't get any bubble at the point of contact but the moment I place the water surface below a certain distance (which is equal to the distance after which the streamline flow breaks down into separate water drops) you start to get multiple bubbles spreading away from the point of contact.
Why is this so ? Why don't we get bubbles in the first case but multiple bubbles in the second one ?
Sorry if it sounds stupid but I can't think of any reason for it.

Not stupid. Explaining puzzling behavior of nature is what physics is for.

One possibility is that in the second case air is entrained in the water flow. The force that water in the stream behind this air exerts on it is sufficient to force the air under the standing water where it later appears as bubbles. These bubbles will surface and flow away from the stream of water as more air bubbles appear behind them.
In the first case, air is carried along only on the surface of the stream of water and when this impinges on the standing water there is not sufficient force to overcome water surface tension, so this air just gets diverted to the side and does not enter the body of water.
